# jQuery: bind within some action causes mutliple executions

Tags: jquery, events, keypress

Okay, i just asked for unbinding particular keypress events. I solved this now with namespaced events. But I got another problem...the function below binds a keypress event after a div is shown by `animate()` . It works well but the keypress event seems to count the times, the function is executed...in my case the `myFnc()` executes when a link is clicked...so when i click the link the `keypress.f` event is fired one time...but when the link is clicked more than one time before i press the key, the keypress event also executed more then one time although i pressed the key only one time....so the fadeToggle() will execute 5 times with one keypress, when the function is executed 5 times before through five clicks ...does anyone understand what i mean and can help me with this?

```
function myFnc() {
        $('#somediv').animate({    
            height: 'toggle'              
        }, 600, function() { 

            $(document).bind('keypress.f', function(event) {

                if($('#secret').is(':visible')) {  

                    if ( event.which == 102 ) {
                        $('.content-2').fadeToggle();
                        $('.content-284').fadeToggle();
                    }
                }
                else {                        
                    $(document).unbind('keypress.f');                        
                }
            });

        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is) and the [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to only apply the animation if it is currently not in progress.. (*if the issue is multiple clicks while the animation is in progress*)

```
function myFnc() {
    var $somediv = $('#somediv');
    if (!$somediv.is(':animated')) {
        $somediv.animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 600, function() {

            $(document).bind('keypress.f', function(event) {

                if ($('#secret').is(':visible')) {

                    if (event.which == 102) {
                        $('.content-2').fadeToggle();
                        $('.content-284').fadeToggle();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $(document).unbind('keypress.f');
                }
            });

        });
    }
}
```

---

another solution would be to always unbind the keypress before binding a new one..

```
$(document).unbind('keypress.f');
$(document).bind('keypress.f', function(event) {...});
```

This way it will always be just one..

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with something like

```
var bound_keypress_f = false;

function myFnc() {
        $('#somediv').animate({    
            height: 'toggle'              
        }, 600, function() { 
            if (!bound_keypress_f) {
                $(document).bind('keypress.f', function(event) {

                    if($('#secret').is(':visible')) {  
                        if ( event.which == 102 ) {
                            $('.content-2').fadeToggle();
                            $('.content-284').fadeToggle();
                        }

                        bound_keypress_f = true;
                    }
                    else {                        
                        $(document).unbind('keypress.f');                        

                        bound_keypress_f = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding 5 keypress.f events (one is bound each time you click the link). You can get around this in a couple different ways:

1) Unbind all keypress.f events before binding the keypress.f event.

2) Bind the keypress.f event when the page loads, and add an if(flag) to the beginning of the function. Whenever the link is clicked, set the flag to true. Set the flag to false when you don't want keypress.f to fire the function.

Comment: Your first solution works well...thank you!! (didn´t try the others)